# Tricky set of redirections needed for URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

If I have a website, say my http://www.website.com, what is the best way to redirect traffic to a `default.aspx` page but not have that shown in the url?

So if the user goes to http://mywebsite.com they get redirected to  http://mywebsite.com/default.aspx?lid=1234 but that is displayed as:

```
http://mywebsite.com?lid=1234
```

When my site goes live (obviously the site is not http://mywebsite.com, but the main url is not relevant) I want to be able to give them the url above.

At the moment its a bit tricky, when we gave them the URL, it didnt have a parameter lid, but now the system requires it.

I changed http://mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com/default.aspx?lid1234 by setting `index.html` as a higher default page and having the code `http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=default.aspx?lid=1234"`

That worked.

If I then apply the standard rewrite rule for removing default.aspx as shown here: http://kitsula.com/Article/URL-Rewriter-Remove-default.aspx-from-the-URL

It almost works. The redirect goes to http://mywebsite.com/?lid=1234

How can I get rid of the `/` after `.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are doing 2 redirects when a single rewrite should do the trick.

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/?$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?lid=1234" />
</rule>
```

If a user comes to `http://www.website.com` or `http://www.website.com/` the url will be rewritten to `http://mywebsite.com/default.aspx?lid=1234`. (but in the user's browser, the displayed url will stay the same)